# GoogleJsonResponse exception while persisting/retrieving entity in appengine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa

I am developing android app with appengine backend.There are two entity classes,User and Book, in bidirectional one to many relationships.A book entity is referred by the books(ArrayList) field in the User entity. When I try to insert a book entity and receive the inserted entity back in the client side, I am getting the GoogleJsonResponseException exception in the client app.Exception message states:

com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: You have just attempted to access field \"owner\" yet this field was not detached when you detached the object. Either dont access this field, or detach it when detaching the object.

This is how I am inserting the book entity:

```
    try {

            Book retrievedBook=endpoint.insertBook(registeredNumber, b).execute();
            if(retrievedBook!=null){
                String message="Success";

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //THE ERROR IS CAUGHT HERE
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

The insertBook method in the UserEndpoint:

```
    @ApiMethod(name = "insertBook")
 public Book insertBook(Book book,@Named("userRegistrationNumber")String userRegistrationNumber) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {
        UserEndpoint ue=new UserEndpoint();



        mgr.getTransaction().begin();

        User u=mgr.find(User.class, userRegistrationNumber);


        u.setBook(book);        

        mgr.flush();
        mgr.getTransaction().commit();

        //To check if key is generated.
          String keyString=KeyFactory.keyToString(book.getBookId());


        //TESTED OK:Check if book is inserted properly..
        User uCheck=mgr.find(User.class, userRegistrationNumber);
        Book b uBooks=(ArrayList<Book>)uCheck.getBooks()get(0);

        //TESTED OK:Testing if able to get owner from book entity...
        User owner=b.getUser();

        return book;

    }catch(Exception e){
        mgr.getTransaction().rollback();
        return null;
    }
    finally {

        mgr.close();
    }

}
```

How can the inserted Book entity be received in the client?

User Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
private String id;
//private String registeredNumber;

private  String userName;
private int sexId;
private String userAddress;
private String pinNumber;
private int ratingCount;
private int reportCount;

private String emailId;
private String interestAreaSubjectId;
private String sharingPolicy;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=com.example.bookemon.Book.class,
        mappedBy="owner",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private ArrayList<Book> books;

 //getters and setters...


}
```

Book Entity class:

```
  @Entity
 public class Book {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key bookId;


private String bookName;
private String bookDescription;
private int categoryId;
private String  publicationYear;
private int reportCount;
private int languageId;
private int ratingCount;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
public User owner;

     ////Getters and setters......
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is very clear. When you detached the object (closed the PM?) you did not have that field present in the object so, if you need it later, you should load it before closing the PM.

Comment: I am closing the entitymanager only in the finally block.that way, the error should not have occured.

Comment: Please tell us why "the error should not have occurred". You have an object and a field is not loaded when passed out of the persistence context. It's down to you to make sure the field is loaded (EAGER setting or FetchPlan). You present no classes

Comment: I have inserted entity class codes.Please check if any error in entity classes.

Comment: so the owner field is marked as LAZY, so it won't be loaded by default. All JPA docs, and specifically those of your JPA provider would tell you how to ensure it is loaded when detaching